# open and close a programme at a specific time using Automator - OSX

Tags: macos, automator

Im trying to write an Automator script that does the following each day :

```
if (TIME = 22:00) {
    open Mail.app 
}

if (TIME = 24:00) {
    close Mail.app 
}
```

I can see how to open and close Mail with the launch application and close application Action, but cant see how to set wrap it in an if block related to the current time ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use Automator for this?  I do similar things on my machines using LaunchAgents in the launchd protocol.

Comment: The only reason is that Automator has a GUI, im not adverse to writing code, but if its a language / framework etc i havnt used before for 1 of small things id rather just drag and drop as there is no learning curve